# Flex - including a host component class that is in a sibling folder

Tags: flex4

I have a FLEX project, in the 'default' folder of which I have 2 sub-folders - "skins" and "scripts". My custom skins and actionscript classes (all defined in "scripts" package namespace) are stored in these sub-folders respectively.

Now, in one of the skins I refer to a AS class that is in the "scripts" folder, say, like this:
[HostComponent("MyCustomButtonClass")]

This obviously reports the error:
*1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: MyCustomButtonClass.*

How do I make the class reference in host-component work?

(If it helps, there is main.mxml in the default package where all these components are used)

Answer (score 0):

Just add both folders to the source path and use package structures.